# Object Custom Link OnClick JavaScript check if page exists before window.open

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a link on an object that contains code similar to the following.

```
var VFBase = "/apex/MyVFPageName_"; 
var DBFld = "{!MyObject__c.MyField__c}"; 
var Suff = "?id={!MyObject__c.Id}"; 
var VFFull = VFBase.concat(DBFld); 
var VFFull = VFFull.concat(Suff); 
window.open(VFFull);
```

So it creates a VF Page name based on a field value on my object that will be something like...

```
/apex/MyVFPageName_A?id={!MyObject__c.Id}

or 

/apex/MyVFPageName_B?id={!MyObject__c.Id}
```

What I want to be able to do is before the window.open is test for the existence of the VF Page.

So if /apex/MyVFPageName_A or /apex/MyVFPageName_B does not exist then I want to instead open a page called /apex/MyVFPageName (which I know will for sure exist)

What I need to know is how I can check for the existence of a given VF page before I attempt to open it.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be certain about visualforce page you can query for that page using javascript API at run time with following code.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
result = sforce.connection.query("Select id,Name from apexpage where name='MYVFPAGENAME'");

records = result.getArray("records");
if(records.length)
{
 //page found write your logic here.
}
```